# Best way to search dataframe by list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with that values in one of column:

```
df.Sample
    POLSD233123
    POLRR419910
    POLAG002144
    DEUOD002139
    MEDOW203919
    ...
```

And I create list from another df with only numeric part of number(different base): for example

```
more = [419910, 983129,9128412,5353463,203919]
```

So in list I have a two number existing in dataframe. I need to create list of common and uncommon value.

When I will have a common, I will create uncommon too. I just write a simple loop in python:

```
listOfRepetitionBase_SNPS = []
for i in range(len(more)):
    temp = baza[baza['Sample'].str.contains(more[i])]
    if len(temp) > 0:
        listOfRepetitionBase_SNPS.append(temp)
    else:
        print("no that record in base,", more[i])
```

And it's work... but data frame has a 90xxx Samples and once run take 5-10 minutes to process. Can someone give me advice on how to make this process faster, maybe by pandas?

The result in this case should be:

```
listOfRepetitionBase_SNPS =  419910, 203919
uncommon =  983129,9128412,5353463
```

Comment: `baza[baza['Sample'].str.contains("|".join(more), regex=True)]` ?

Comment: Leaves the contents unchanged though, OP wants values form the list @Rakesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn `more` into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and check membership with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) over all strings in the dataframe:

```
s = set(map(str, more))
common = [i for i in s if any(i in row for row in df.Sample.values)]
# ['419910', '203919']
uncommon  = list(s.difference(common))
#['9128412', '5353463', '983129']
```

Comment: Thank U, it's very helpful and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex

**Ex:**

```
baza = pd.DataFrame({"Sample":['POLSD233123', 'POLRR419910', 'POLAG002144', 'DEUOD002139', 'MEDOW203919']})
more = [419910, 983129,9128412,5353463,203919]
c = "|".join(map(str, more))
common_list =  baza[baza['Sample'].str.contains(c, regex=True)].values.tolist()
uncommon =  baza[~baza['Sample'].str.contains(c, regex=True)].values.tolist()

import re

print([re.search(r"(\d+)", i[0]).group(1) for i in common_list])
print([re.search(r"(\d+)", i[0]).group(1) for i in uncommon])
```

**Output:**

```
['419910', '203919']
['233123', '002144', '002139']
```

Answer (score 1):

i like `numpy` here.

> data

```
    0
0  POLSD233123
1  POLRR419910
2  POLAG002144
3  DEUOD002139
4  MEDOW203919
```

---

using [np.setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```
a = np.setdiff1d(df[0].str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0], more)
##print(a)
array(['002139', '002144', '233123'], dtype=object)
```

---

using [np.intersect1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

```
a = np.intersect1d(df[0].str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0], more)
##print(a) 
array(['203919', '419910'], dtype=object)
```